他のアプリで停止中の楽曲を再生/再開したい
YouTube Musicなど他のアプリで再生を中断・停止している曲をAndroidの自作アプリから再開したいです。Bluetoothなどのメディアボタンの再生・停止ボタンを押した時と同じような挙動が好ましいです。
これは画面を開いて再生再開するのが面倒で自動化したいからです。
通知センターのメディアコントローラーで楽曲が待機していない場合でも、過去のセッションから再生を再開できると助かります。
検索してもMedia Playerなどの再生方法などしか出てこなく、困っているので情報提供していただけると助かります。
具体的なコードや参考になるページを貼っていただけると嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。
